# How to map JSON request to String using SPRING REST

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

I have a REST API with uri :

```
POST
/version/path/generic
Consumes : Application/JSON
```

The JSON can be of different format. Any valid JSON can be input of this API. So to support this in the webmethod, how can we map it in JAVA ?

```
String 
Object
MAP
```

Not getting proper json in any of the above formats ?

Comment: Which approaches did you try so far? Where did you fail? I am not sure, but mapping JSON of any structure to something in Java should be rather difficult. You only could map the JSON as raw string.

Comment: have tried mapping it to string, which didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map a method parameter like that:

```
@RequestBody String json
```

and use a JSON parser, for example Gson to map it to JAVA classes afteron like that:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
SomeJavaClass jsonMapping = gson.fromJson(json, SomeJavaClass.class);
```

Comment: What implementation are you using - JERSEY ?

Answer (score 0):

Make an abstraction in Java, where you use a `Map` for the generic key-value mapping of a JSON object, a `List` for JSON arrays and regular `String` / `Integer` for JSON values.